# Customised Setter and Getter in Lombok

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Lombok [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation will dumbly add setter and getter of fields on the annotated class.

how to add condition based setter in lombok?

```
public void setName(final String name){
      this.name = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(name);
}
```

is there any support in lombok like this `@Setter(condition = StringUtils.isEmpty)`

i have searched in lombok doc's i see no explanation regarding my issue.

Comment: Why not write a normal Java class?

Comment: ya i agree normal class would be fine . but , it contains lot of setter and getters code which i wan't to get rid off. that is the reason why i choose lombok.

Answer (score 3):

you can just add another setter, it will override lombok's implenmention

Comment: is there any way i can skip writing another setter. like passing condition in lombok annotaton?.

Comment: I now seems understand what you are trying to do, but it's not support at the time by lombok. If you want to add a template to setters of all fields, maybe a good solution is to modify the code generating template of the ide.